# Grails SQL match criteria

Tags: sql, grails

My case are searching people over interest types, age, activities and so on. And at least one information must match and show the result.
For example: It must be a woman within 25-31 years old range and (optionally) I would like to know people that speak: english, german and italian, and my interests are: going to party, people that speak my language, do activities outside. Another profile create is almost the same with some information are equals.

Age and sex are the main lock of matching the criteria. And others are optional, the example above, if a person speak japanese and italian and must be a woman within 25-31 years old, show in results.

But I'm stuck where I want to find people that has speak any of 3 language, or interests, how can I loop through it(I have an array)? Should I get all results and then make a method the compare? Or should I use `createCriteria()`
My code is static:

```
def e = User.executeQuery("from User as u where (u.profile.sexType = 2 and u.profile.ageRangeType = 2) > (select Profile as p where ")
```

My english is not the best.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping by the other criteria and doing a count on the languages column.  Then you use a HAVING clause to find those who know more then 3 languages.

```
SELECT User, COUNT (Languages) 
FROM Profile 
WHERE (Other user criteria)
GROUP BY User
HAVING COUNT (Languages) > 2
```

Comment: the group by User shouldn't be a column, not a table?

Comment: Possibly.  I am unfamiliar with your data structure.  But yes, the Group by is done on the columns SELECTed. You will need to put each column that you do not aggregate (AVG, MIN, MAX, or in this case COUNT) into the group by clause, or your query will fail.